# Delay circuit using CMOS inverters

Tags: inverter, cmos, delay

I'm trying to design a circuit that has a delay using inverters; any idea how to control the delays?

[image]

Comment: Look up 'Method of Logical Effort'. The delays in an inverter chain is an entire chapter of study in digital CMOS design books. In short, it depends on the driving strength of the FETs used and the capacitive loading at the output of each stage. Method of logical effort provides mathematical analysis and optimization theory into this.

Comment: @alayoiskgfbfqhxjiw thank you very much for the great reference!

Answer (score 8):

You control the delay by changing the number of inverters you have in series.

If you don't care about silicon area, you can connect the gate terminals of dummy transistors to get more capacitance....just connect the sources and drains to ground or Vdd.

Comment: It may be worth adding a note that while this will change the delay, P/V/T will also change it (perhaps significantly depending on the technology), so precise results may not be repeatable in practice outside of the simulation.

Comment: @nanofarad Good point. Variations in P/V/T can give a factor of five difference in delay, if we're talking about military applications.

Answer (score 2):

CMOS output impedance is  low, and input impedance is high, so it is possible to add delay between inverters with resistors and capacitors, but that changes the input risetime and is not optimal (because slow risetime is associated with power dissipation and oscillation problems) and filters out short pulses.

A Schmitt trigger inverter can be employed for longer delays, using resistors and capacitors, because it is not
sensitive to slow risetime problems.  The bandpass
for signals, though, is still decreased.

A cleaner
solution is a delay line (just a long path of wire),
as is frequently seen on memory module circuit boards.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a delay you can use a capacitor (for voltage delay ) or a inductor (for current delay).If you want voltage delay you can connect the capacitor in parallel with a MOSFET.If you want current delay you can connect the inductor in series with the BE junction of a BJT(flyback diode is required in this case).

Answer (score 1):

If you're not looking for something that would be designed on an IC, but a discrete approach with all N and P mosfets respectively equal, then changing the number of inverters changes the delay, as does changing the supply voltage. A bunch of 74HC04 or CD4069 in series, with a Schmitt trigger at the output to restore the edge rate, do very well as voltage-adjustable delay elements.